# I want to upload a profile picture with symfony2 and doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In User.php (Entity name is User), I have a field in User entity named `userPic` , type String

In file UserType.php  I mention `userPic` as shown below :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('userFullname')
        ->add('userName')
        ->add('userEmail')
        ->add('userPassword')
        ->add('userPic', 'file', array ('label'=>'profile Picture'))
        ->add('gender','choice',array('choices' => array('m' => 'Male', 'f' => 'Female')))

        ->add('isActive')
    ;
}
```

Now in the controller I'm getting the form fields as shown below

```
/**
 * Creates a new User entity.
 *
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new User();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return $this->render('MWANRegisterBundle:User:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Where do I have to give the path in which I want to save the picture? How can I save the uploaded file in my desired directory and save directory path in database?

Comment: From the official documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

Comment: i already have User entity class where i have getter setter
setUserPic()
getUserPic() I'm stucked where i have to metion the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an upload method in your entity. Check this link for more details http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

```
public function uploadFile()
{
    // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
    if (null === $this->getFile()) {
        return;
    }

    // use the original file name here but you should
    // sanitize it at least to avoid any security issues

    // move takes the target directory and then the
    // target filename to move to
    $this->getFile()->move($this->getUploadDir(), $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName());

    // set the path property to the filename where you've saved the file
    $this->path = $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName();

    // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
    $this->file = null;
}

/**
 * Creates a new User entity.
 *
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new User();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        // Upload file
        $entity->uploadFile();    

        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return $this->render('MWANRegisterBundle:User:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Christian's answer is valid, however I'd just like to point out more specificaly how to do what is asked. Simply do :

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $file = $form->getData()['file'];
    $file->move('/your/path/to/your/file', 'yourFileName');
    // Do the rest
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Guys I have a Question kindly Guide me accordingly i shall be grateful. the question is related to FOS-user-Bundle i want embed roles in custom form which i have created in RegisterType. i have extended my User entity from base entity

Comment: For a new question feel free to create a new one, as comments are not for this usage. Moreover, it will get a much better visibility than in a comment.

Comment: thanks for informing, since my reputation here is too low that's why Stakeoverflow not permitting me to ask many questions.